# Mongo DB aggregation pipeline sort on nested array object values

Tags: mongodb, sorting, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, aggregation

I have mongo documents with the following structure:

```
{
    name: 'AKL to DUD Via CHC',
    rates: [
        {
            container_id: 'abc',
            buyRate: 380
        },
        {
            container_id: 'def',
            buyRate: 410
        }
    ]
}
{
    name: 'AKL to DUD',
    rates: [
        {
            container_id: 'abc',
            buyRate: 400
        },
        {
            container_id: 'def',
            buyRate: 420
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like to have a sort in my aggregation pipeline based on the `buyRate` of a specific `container_id`, e.g. if I passed in a `container_id` of `abc` I would like to sort on the `buyRate` of just `abc` so that (in this case) the second document is returned first.

I can get it working by adding in a field with rates filtered by the `container_id` and then sorting on that but it seems overly complex:

```
db.services.aggregate([
    { $addFields: { "containerBuyRate":
            { $filter: {
                input: "$rates",
                as: "rate",
                cond: { $eq: [ "$$rate.container_id", "abc") ] }
            }}
     }},
     { $sort: {'containerBuyRate.buyRate': -1}}
])
```

Is there a more concise way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach is fine.

**Another way:**

> Difference is `$addFields` will add one more field as an object.

[Working example.](https://mongoplayground.net/p/KABcRTqu5Fz)

```
db.getCollection('Example').aggregate([
  { $addFields: {
    containerBuyRate: {$arrayElemAt: [ "$rates", { $indexOfArray: [ "$rates.container_id", "abc" ] } ] }}
  },
  { $sort: {'containerBuyRate.buyRate': -1}}
])
```

**Output:**

```js
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000002"),
    "containerBuyRate": {
      "buyRate": 405,
      "container_id": "abc"
    },
    "name": "AKL to DUD Via CHC",
    "rates": [
      {
        "buyRate": 405,
        "container_id": "abc"
      },
      {
        "buyRate": 500,
        "container_id": "def"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000001"),
    "containerBuyRate": {
      "buyRate": 400,
      "container_id": "abc"
    },
    "name": "AKL to DUD",
    "rates": [
      {
        "buyRate": 400,
        "container_id": "abc"
      },
      {
        "buyRate": 420,
        "container_id": "def"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "containerBuyRate": {
      "buyRate": 380,
      "container_id": "abc"
    },
    "name": "AKL to DUD Via CHC",
    "rates": [
      {
        "buyRate": 380,
        "container_id": "abc"
      },
      {
        "buyRate": 410,
        "container_id": "def"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000003"),
    "containerBuyRate": {
      "buyRate": 300,
      "container_id": "abc"
    },
    "name": "AKL to DUD Via CHC",
    "rates": [
      {
        "buyRate": 300,
        "container_id": "abc"
      },
      {
        "buyRate": 700,
        "container_id": "def"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000004"),
    "containerBuyRate": {
      "buyRate": 100,
      "container_id": "abc"
    },
    "name": "AKL to DUD Via CHC",
    "rates": [
      {
        "buyRate": 1000,
        "container_id": "def"
      },
      {
        "buyRate": 100,
        "container_id": "abc"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Thank you @Alex to point out my mistake on the last solution.

Comment: It's completely wrong. First of all if you run your aggregation on the OPs data you get 2 documents, not 3: https://mongoplayground.net/p/FJsbD84cCwA Secondly, you change order of elements in the array which may have side effects. Most importantly  $sort doesn't sort by  first element but by element with max value. Here https://mongoplayground.net/p/OjtWJd1OgqG  I only changed `{container_id: "def", buyRate: 410}` to `{container_id: "def", buyRate: 510}` and it changed order of documents in the output.

Comment: @AlexBlex `1)` I have tried with one more documents. So the result is in 3 documents. `2)` `$sort doesn't sort by the first element but by element with max value.`  Could you please give me any link so I can refer this sentence, maybe I am confused here. `3)` You changed value buyrate to 510 and it changed the order of document which is correct as per OP's requirement. Thank you!

Comment: I changed buyRate for subdoc with container_id: "def". It should not change order if we sort by  buyRate of subdocs with container_id: "abc", right?

Comment: @AlexBlex, Thank you to point me in the right direction. I had completely missed out negative scenario.

Comment: That's much better. Sorry I couldn't find a link to the docs about sorting. I guess it's the case where stackoverflow fills the gaps in the documentation.

Comment: @AlexBlex, No worry, I have tested on my local setup and found that you are correct about the sorting. My bad. BTW Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

For sorting `containerBuyRate` array you need to unwind it and sort it

```
db.services.aggregate([
     { $addFields: { "containerBuyRate":
        { $filter: {
            input: "$rates",
            as: "rate",
            cond: { $eq: [ "$$rate.container_id", "abc" ] }
        }}
     }},
     { $unwind: "$containerBuyRate" },
     { $sort: {"containerBuyRate.buyRate": -1}},
     { $group: { 
         _id: "$_id",
         containerBuyRate: {$push: "$containerBuyRate"},
         name: { $first: "$name"},
         rates: {$first: "$rates"} 
     }}
])
```